# jq - delete parent without deleting children

Tags: jq

Let's say `input.json` is:

```
{
    "useless": "stuff",
    "deleteMe": [
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "baz": "fizz"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want it to look like

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": "fizz"
}
```

In other words, I want to delete the parent(s) but preserve the children. I'm seeing a lot about `jq 'del()'` but that seems to delete the children as well in my testing. If I knew all the names of the child elements I could extract them into a new object, but the list of keys varies so I'm hoping for a more global approach. How do I remove everything but the children?

Comment: Seems to me you're looking for `.deleteMe[]` ([try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/WHzCZXgRIx)). You just need the path of an array to extract its content.

Comment: @Aaron oh... yeah I guess I could do that and then read it back into the file. Feel free to write an answer if you want the rep!

Comment: You would have had to write back to the file when using `del()` too actually, `jq` doesn't do in-place edition currently (see [this issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/105) for discussion and progress on the topic ; and note the need to use a temporary/work file rather than directly writing back to the input file). And there's not much for an answer there honestly, thanks for the rep offer but I'll pass :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use jq in conjunction with `sponge`, e.g.

```
< input.json jq '.deleteMe[0]' | sponge input.json
```

There are several other eminently reasonable solutions, depending in part on the detailed requirements, e.g.

```
< input.json jq '.deleteMe[]' > input.tmp && mv input.tmp input.json
```